# How can I replace h5py.AttributeManager with a custom class?

Tags: python-3.x, h5py

I want to store an astropy `Quantity` in an hdf5 attribute.

What I'm doing at the moment is this:

```
from astropy import units
import h5py


length_1 = 5.3 * units.meter

# -- Write attribute ----------
with h5py.File("./temp.hdf5", "w") as data:
    # write value
    data.attrs.create("length", length_1.value)
    # write unit  
    data.attrs.create("lengthUnit", length_1.unit.to_string())

# -- Read attribute -----------
with h5py.File("./temp.hdf5", "r") as data:
    # read value
    lengthValue = data.attrs["length"]
    # read unit
    lengthUnit = data.attrs["lengthUnit"]

    # recreate length as Quantity
    length_2 = lengthValue * units.Unit(lengthUnit)
```

However, it would be helpful if I could modify the getter/setter process of the [`AttributeManager`](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/07f3c362887563c1040b10d2cbd8cca49ceac1b9/h5py/_hl/attrs.py#L30) to handle any `Quantity` as I do here. 
E.g.

```
class QuantityAttributeManager(h5py.AttributeManager):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

    # __setitem__ uses create
    def create(self, name, data, shape=None, dtype=None):

        if isinstance(data, units.Quantity):
            super().create(
                    name,
                    data.value
                    )
            super().create(
                    "{:s}Unit".format(name),
                    data.unit.to_string().encode("utf-8")
                    )
        else:
            super().create(name, data, shape, dtype)

    # def __getitem__

    # [...]

with h5py.File("./temp.hdf5", "w") as data:
    # really this should be:
    #    data.attrs["length"] = length
    # and this is where the problem lies
    attr = QuantityAttributeManager(data["/"])
    attr["length"] = length_1

    print(list(attr.keys()))  # ['length', 'lengthUnit']
```

The `.attrs` attribute is defined as ([[source]](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/d3ba9449827a9dc33d6d75409805b71567c9973b/h5py/_hl/base.py#L268))

```
@property
def attrs(self):
    """ Attributes attached to this object """
    from . import attrs
    with phil:
        return attrs.AttributeManager(self)
```

in [`HLObject`](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/d3ba9449827a9dc33d6d75409805b71567c9973b/h5py/_hl/base.py#L210), which [`Dataset`](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/cae0c01d4d3589cde20fe49fc7df750dfbe94a51/h5py/_hl/dataset.py#L224) and [`Group`](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/e0dd0ff5461b7192e58e996f865544e60a7ba11a/h5py/_hl/group.py#L31) inherit. [`File`](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/78a56dcd768e7bea5220bd8d13db683d3d6c4f0e/h5py/_hl/files.py#L197) inherits [`Group`](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/e0dd0ff5461b7192e58e996f865544e60a7ba11a/h5py/_hl/group.py#L31) but overrides `.attrs`.

The best option I can see is to redirect the `from . import attrs` line to use `QuantityAttributeManager` instead, but I'm not sure how.
(Preferably without being too hacky.)

Comment: Do you really want to modify `attrs` for all levels?  Why not just `Dataset`?  I'd tie it to the object being stored, rather than the method of storing.

Comment: For consistency in behaviour, it would make sense to use the same AttributeManager for all types. Even if it was just changed for `Dataset`, I would still have to catch every method that created or returned a `Dataset`.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be to monkey patch, but then the new attribute manager would always be used.

```
h5py._hl.attrs.AttributeManager = QuantityAttributeManager

with h5py.File("./temp.hdf5", "w") as data:
    data.attrs["length"] = length

    print(list(data.attrs.keys()))  # ['length', 'lengthUnit']
```